# How To Count Joined Table Record

Tags: mysql

Honestly, idk the right questions on my case...

let's say i have 2 tables,

```
Table User                  Table Attendance

|id|name|address|           |id|user_id|attendance_status|
-----------------           ------------------------------
|1 |July|NY City|           |1 |   1   |      Late       |
|2 |Remy|London |           |2 |   2   |      On Time    |
|3 |Mike|Turin  |           |3 |   2   |      On Time    |
                            |4 |   3   |      On Time    |
                            |5 |   3   |      On Time    |
                            |6 |   3   |      On Time    |
```

my questions is how to displaying all record with counting attendance_status is On Time, approxiately like this :

```
|user_id|name|total|
--------------------
|   1   |July|  0  |
|   2   |Remy|  2  |
|   3   |Mike|  3  |
```

but after i tried my query, i got like this :

```
|user_id|name|total|
--------------------
|   2   |Remy|  2  |
|   3   |Mike|  3  |
```

please help me to solve my case, Thanks

*note: If you know the query and know how to use it on eloquent laravel, that's better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query:

```
SELECT
    t1.id AS user_id,
    t1.name,
    COALESCE(t2.total, 0) AS total
FROM User t1
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT user_id, COUNT(*) AS total
    FROM Attendance
    WHERE attendance_status = 'On Time'
    GROUP BY user_id
) t2
    ON t1.id = t2.user_id
```

**Demo here:**

## SQLFiddle

Comment: oops, i didn't realize you have change query from `INNER JOIN` into `LEFT JOIN` :D , thanks bud